# Realm: Filter Child Element by Value Using Subquery in Swift

Tags: realm, nspredicate

Here is a simplified view of my Realm data structure:

```
//Entry
class Entry: Object{
  let fieldValues = List<FieldValue>()
}

//FieldValue
class FieldValue: Object{
  @objc dynamic var name = ""
  @objc dynamic var flightTime = 0
  @objc dynamic var bool = false
  @objc dynamic var text = ""
  @objc dynamic var type = ""
}
```

I want to filter a result set of entries (`Results<Entry>`) by one of three scenarios:

1. `flightTime > 0`
2. `bool = true`
3. `text != ''`

I'm building an array of `NSPredicate`s to capture each potential scenario, but I can't get any of them to work. Here's my `flightTime` predicate:

```
let value = "Night"    
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY fieldValues.name = %@ AND SUBQUERY(fieldValues, $fieldValue, $fieldValue.flightTime > 0).@count > 0", value)
```

After this predicate, entries still show up that have `fieldValue`s with the name "Night" and a `flightTime` that is 0.

Once I get the predicate format right, I figure I'll be able to do the `bool` and `text` filters without much trouble. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you want query "(ANY fieldValues.name = 'Night') AND (ANY fieldValues.flightTime > 0)" or "SUBQUERY(fieldValues, $fieldValue, $fieldValue.name = 'Night' AND $fieldValue.flightTime > 0).@count > 0"?

Comment: I think you want to pull both the conditions into the SUBQUERY. As it is right now you will get all entries that have a fieldvalue with the name 'Night' and which have a fieldvalue with flight time above zero. But no requirement that both of these conditions have to be on the _same_ fieldvalue.

Comment: Yep, you are both right. It looks like I have to put both conditions in the subquery and it seems to work: `SUBQUERY(fieldValues, $fieldValue, $fieldValue.name = %@ AND $fieldValue.flightTime > 0).@count > 0` Thanks!